# How do I stop a fixed object from going outside of its parent container?

Tags: html, css

I am currently making a site for school and on that site I have a sidebar with links in it. I want this to be visible everywhere on the side so I used position: fixed. But now it no longer remains within the space of its parent but start at the very top of the page.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 250%;
  color: #000000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #591500;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

body {
  background-size: 600% 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

article {
  width: 900px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 110px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

aside {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 3000px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

footer {
  width: 1200px;
  float: left;
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
}

header.intro {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

header#intro {
  background-image: url("../images/banner4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 350%;
  color: white;
  width: 1200px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

header#intro h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 225%;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FFDA45;
  border: black solid 1px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 235px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 200%;
}

li a:hover {
  border: red solid 5px;
  background-color: #E8B53F;
}

div#wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.middle {
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-color: #000033;
  width: 110px;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #00000070;
  color: #3498db;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.btn i {
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.btn:hover i {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  background: #3498db;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: -110%;
  top: 90%;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  animation: aaa 1s 1;
  top: -10%;
  left: -10%;
}

@keyframes aaa {
  0% {
    left: -110%;
    top: 90%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 10%;
    top: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    top: -10%;
    left: -10%;
  }
}


/* dit stijlblad is gemaakt in 2019 */
```

```html
<link href="styles/eersteStijl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">


<body>
  <header id="intro">
    <h1>The Last of Us information page</h1>
  </header>

  <nav>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="TLOU part II.html">TLOU part II</a></li>
      <li><a href="Video's.html">Video's</a></li>
      <li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

  <article>

    article

  </article>

  <aside>

    <section class="middle">
      <a class="btn" href="https://nl-nl.facebook.com/TLOUPS/" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/naughty_dog" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-wikipedia-w"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn" href="https://www.instagram.com/_the.last.of.us/" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
      </a>
      <a class="btn" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQpdSVF_k_w" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
      </a>
    </section>

  </aside>

  <footer>copyright</footer>
```

As can be seen the side bar goes over the top of the page is there a way for it to not do this and stick inside the ? I would like the sidebar to be the exact same except when its at the top then I would like it to be hidden. I tried it with overflow hidden but it doesn't seem to work.

I also don't seem to be able to see the side bar unless I am in full screen which is not a problem but might be nice to know if someone checks out the code.

Comment: why are u using float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are just learning, but I changed the explicit sizing rules to flex, for my sanity, and removed some of the other rules simply for readability, but should not impact the end goal of the fixed object; you can still use your way if you want.

One solution to this is using the `sticky` value for the [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) property. You will have to do some responsive adjustments for smaller screens but I didn't include it because I am not sure what you are going for.

> Sticky: The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, and then offset relative to its nearest scrolling ancestor and containing block (nearest block-level ancestor), including table-related elements, based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left. The offset does not affect the position of any other elements.

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 250%;
  color: #000000;
}

h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 180%;
  color: #591500;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: black;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

footer {
  height: 25px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

header.intro {
  font-size: 100%;
  color: black;
}

header#intro {
  background-image: url("../images/banner4.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 350%;
  color: white;
}

header#intro h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 225%;
  color: black;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

li a {
  background-color: #FFDA45;
  border: black solid 1px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

li a:hover {
  border: red solid 5px;
  background-color: #E8B53F;
}

.middle {
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  position: sticky;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 30%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px -5px #00000070;
  color: #3498db;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.btn i {
  line-height: 90px;
  font-size: 26px;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}

.btn:hover i {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.btn::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 120%;
  height: 120%;
  background: #3498db;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  left: -110%;
  top: 90%;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  animation: aaa 1s 1;
  top: -10%;
  left: -10%;
}

@keyframes aaa {
  0% {
    left: -110%;
    top: 90%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 10%;
    top: -30%;
  }
  100% {
    top: -10%;
    left: -10%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="styles/eersteStijl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

<header id="intro">
  <h1>The Last of Us information page</h1>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="TLOU part II.html">TLOU part II</a></li>
      <li><a href="Video's.html">Video's</a></li>
      <li><a href="Music.html">Music</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<main>
  <article>
    article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long
    text
    <br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long
    long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with
    long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article
    with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br>    article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long
    text
    <br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long
    long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with
    long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article
    with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br>    article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long
    text
    <br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long
    long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with
    long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article
    with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br>    article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long
    text
    <br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long
    long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with
    long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article
    with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br>    article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long
    text
    <br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long
    long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with
    long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article with long long text<br> article
    with long long text<br> article with long long text<br>
  </article>
  <aside class="middle">
    <a class="btn" href="https://nl-nl.facebook.com/TLOUPS/" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="https://twitter.com/naughty_dog" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-wikipedia-w"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="https://www.instagram.com/_the.last.of.us/" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="btn" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQpdSVF_k_w" target="_blank">
      <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
    </a>
  </aside>

</main>

<footer>copyright</footer>
```